# Closing all open cursors

Tags: oracle11g, cursor

Question:

Is there a way to close all the cursors you are using in the database? To my knowledge one can only close a cursor one at a time or as a collective by association with tables using a FOR loop.

Reason behind question:

I have been getting the "maximum open cursors exceeded" when running SOME scripts for creating and populating tables in SQL Developer. I can usually run additional scripts after one has failed because of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may ask your Oracle DBA to increase open_cursors parameter at database level to solve your problem(This will require downtime).

Comment: The thing is I am Logged in as the System Admin. Should the error still happen?

Comment: Yes. You need to increase the parameter value at database level. It will not help, even if you are logged in through sys admin account.